# Appium freezes when finding an element on native app view

Tags: android, ruby, cordova, cucumber, appium

I am trying to locate an element on an android hybrid app which has been built using Cordova. I have verified the context and it is the native app view.

Currently using Appium v1.65, Android v7.1.1 API 26, ruby 2.2.0 and Cordova.

When I try to locate `$driver.find_element(:xpath => "//android.widget.FrameLayout")` which is the highest element on the page. Appium server tries to search for the element. Appium spits out:

```
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: 
{"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":
{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.FrameLayout",
"context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: 
{"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":
{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.FrameLayout",
"context":""
,"multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 
'//android.widget.FrameLayout' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' 
 multiple: false
```

Appium does not spit anything else out after this it stays silent. It feels like Appium cannot even see the page.

Thus I have to hit `control + c`. Can somebody advise if they have faced this issue when trying to automate an hybrid android app built with Cordova?

Comment: Is there API 26 for Android 7.1? Would it be possible for you to try this on 7.1.1 (API 25)?

Comment: @AnishPillai I have tried that but each release within Virtual Device Configuration has a fixed API. I have tried Release name O: API 26; but that is still having issues and people are still fixing these within the open source community. I am very short for time so I may just end up testing it manually. I came across this article though I think you may find it useful if you ever want automate a hybrid cordova app. http://elgris.github.io/blog/2_appium_vs_calabash/. Do you have any other suggestions? if so please let me know.

Comment: Hi Shafiq, I think API 26 is the Android O version which is still not out. And I don't think that Appium supports it as of now. So the only option is to try with API 25 or before, if you want to go for automation.